# Как записать в вектор значения?

Tags: c++

Как записать в вектор значение из cin?

Comment: Поэлементно :) Или написать свой оператор...

Comment: Из вашего вопроса неясно _ записывать собираетесь в уже существующие элементы или  добавлять в конец. В общем случаи, можно записать  в уже существующие элементы, а остальные значения добавлять в конец.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете тип `T` и количество `n` нужных значений:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin), n, std::back_inserter(vector));
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку неизвестн  вектор каких типов инициализируем, не известно количество элементов в нем, неизвестно  количество  и корректность вводимых
данных, нужно написать код для общего случая:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename Tp>
void fill_in(std::vector<Tp>& v, std::istream& in)
{
    for (auto& el : v) {
        in >> el;
        if (!in) {
            in.clear();
            in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        }
    }   
    using Input = std::istream_iterator<Tp>;
    auto back = std::back_inserter(v);
    std::copy(Input(in), Input(), back);    
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(3);
    fill_in(v, std::cin);
    //ипользуем  вектор 
    return 0;
}
```

функция обрабатывает корректность ввода, но намерения могут быть разными, так что эта обработка может быть разной. А также может быть разным и способ заполнения вектора, относительно необходимости записи в конец или поверх данных. Так что ответ на ваш вопрос, по любому, не может быть однозначным.